# Elide Puppet parameters based on conditional

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I have the following resource declared in a Puppet `define`.  There are some parameters beginning with `auth_*` that control authentication.  I'd like to be able to pass that block of parameters, or not pass them, based on the value of a boolean variable i.e. `$use_authentication`.

It seems that an `if` statement won't work here, and I don't think that a "selector" will do so either.  Felix Frank had a really useful answer in the very closely related question "[conditional within define in puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459241/conditional-within-define-in-puppet)", but I don't think that strategy will work here, because the parameters that need to be elided are nested two layers deep.

```
apache::vhost { "$name-non-ssl":
    servername => $vhost_name,
    docroot => $document_root,
    port => 80,

    access_log_file => 'access.log',
    access_log_format => 'vhost_common',
    error_log_file => 'error.log',

    directories => [
         {path => $document_root,
          auth_type => 'Basic',
          auth_name => "$name",
          auth_user_file => '/somefile.pwd',
          auth_require => 'valid-user',
          rewrites => [
              {
                  comment => "rule1",
                  rewrite_base => "/",
                  rewrite_rule => ['^index\.html$ - [L]']
              },
              {
                  comment => "rule2",
                  rewrite_cond => ['%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f', '%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d'],
                  rewrite_rule => ['. /index.html [L]']
              }
          ]}
    ],
}
```

The following gives a syntax error: `Syntax error at 'if'; expected '}'`

```
apache::vhost { "$name-non-ssl":
    ... same as previous ...
    directories => [
         {path => $document_root,

          if $use_authentication {
              auth_type => 'Basic',
              auth_name => "$name",
              auth_user_file => '/somefile.pwd',
              auth_require => 'valid-user',
          }

          rewrites => [
              ...same as before...
          ]}
    ],
}
```

Comment: A conditional would actually work here if you put the declaration inside of it. Felix's answer would also work if done within the class definition. I also answered a question similar to this recently at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530656/optionally-passing-a-parameter-to-puppet-resource/40531449#40531449. So the good news is that you have several options available to you based on readily available information.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I don't understand how the working conditional syntax would look?  I updated the question with an example that failed.  I don't want to repeat the entire `apache::vhost` resource, I only want to conditionalize the `auth_*` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tough to handle because you want to dynamically fill in some key/value pairs in a hash that is an element of an array which is a parameter value.

#### Option 1: Build the hash outside of the resource declaration

```
$auth_settings = {
     auth_type => 'Basic',
     auth_name => "$name",
     auth_user_file => '/somefile.pwd',
     auth_require => 'valid-user',
}
$base_dir1 = {path => $document_root,
      rewrites => [
          {
              comment => "rule1",
              rewrite_base => "/",
              rewrite_rule => ['^index\.html$ - [L]']
          },
          {
              comment => "rule2",
              rewrite_cond => ['%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f', '%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d'],
              rewrite_rule => ['. /index.html [L]']
          }
      ]
}
if $use_authentication {
    $real_dir1 = merge($base_dir1, $auth_settings)
}
else {
    $real_dir1 = $base_dir1
}

apache::vhost { "$name-non-ssl":
    servername => $vhost_name,
    docroot => $document_root,
    port => 80,
    access_log_file => 'access.log',
    access_log_format => 'vhost_common',
    error_log_file => 'error.log',
    directories => [ $real_dir1 ],
}
```

Granted, it goes a little wild with the variables.

#### Option 2: Create a custom function

Write a function that takes what is `$base_dir1` above and the boolean value for `$use_authentication`, and returns the merged hash if appropriate.

```
apache::vhost { "$name-non-ssl":
    servername => $vhost_name,
    docroot => $document_root,
    port => 80,

    access_log_file => 'access.log',
    access_log_format => 'vhost_common',
    error_log_file => 'error.log',

    directories => [ add_auth($use_authentication, { ... }) ],
}
```

#### Option 3: Inline that

You can nonchalantly do the merge right in the resource declaration. Use a selector to decide what to merge. Readability is out the window with this one.

```
apache::vhost { "$name-non-ssl":
    servername => $vhost_name,
    docroot => $document_root,
    port => 80,

    access_log_file => 'access.log',
    access_log_format => 'vhost_common',
    error_log_file => 'error.log',

    directories => [ merge({path => $document_root,
      rewrites => [
          {
              comment => "rule1",
              rewrite_base => "/",
              rewrite_rule => ['^index\.html$ - [L]']
          },
          {
              comment => "rule2",
              rewrite_cond => ['%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f', '%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d'],
              rewrite_rule => ['. /index.html [L]']
          }
      ]
    }, $use_authentication ? {
         true => {
             auth_type => 'Basic',
             auth_name => "$name",
             auth_user_file => '/somefile.pwd',
             auth_require => 'valid-user',
         },
         default => {}
       }
     )
   ],
}
```

I didn't bother testing this monster. Not even sure the braces line up.

You might get away with a compromise between (1) and (3), but please lean towards the former.